# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ap' was corrupted

Tags: c++

I ran into above problem when I ran following little piece of code in visual C++ 2010 Express.

When I used CodeBlocks, inner `for` loop couldn't be executed completely because of line (A).

Couldn't figure out why. Thanks for help!

```
int main()
{
    int* ap[10];
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        *(ap+j) = new int[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            *((ap+j)+i) = *(ap+j)+i;//(A)
            **((ap+j)+i) = j * 10 + i;
            cout<<setw(6)<<**((ap+j)+i);
        }
        cout<<endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why say `*(ap+j)` instead of the conventional `ap[j]`?

Comment: Do you think `*((ap+j)+i)` is different to `*(ap+j+i)`?

Comment: Why say *(ap+j) instead of the conventional ap[j]? –  Kos 1 hour ago

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
*((ap+j)+i) = *(ap+j)+i;//(A)
```

can be rewritten as

```
ap[j+i] = ap[j]+i;//(A)
```

and you can clearly see this can write out-of-bounds when j+i > 10.

You probably meant `ap[j][i]` or equivalently `*(*(ap+j)+i)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply but the problem still exists!

Comment: You also have `**((ap+j)+i)` and similar expressions all around. As the next step, try rewriting the whole code to use the `[]` notation, it should help you see what happens and how it's different from what you expected

Comment: int main(){
 int* ap[10];
 for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
  ap[j] = new int[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   ap[j+i] = ap[j]+i;
   *ap[j+i] = j * 10 + i;
   cout<<setw(6)<<*ap[j+i];
  }
  cout<<endl;
 }
 
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: You still have `*ap[j+i]` that accesses out of bounds.

Comment: When I remove use pointers and use 2D array instead, no problem at all. However, I think the use of pointers should be equivalent and I don't understand why pointers don't work here. Thanks!

Comment: It _can_ be equivalent, but isn't in this form. Look at the order of operations: `**((ap+j)+i)` has the order of operations "add, add, dereference, dereference" while `ap[j][i]` or equivalent `*(*(ap+j)+i)` has "add, dereference, add, dereference". Does that show you where the problem is?

Comment: To Kos:

Following program works. However, the wierd thing is when I comment line (B), the problem comes back. May I know why? Thanks!

======================================
int main(){
 int* ap[10];
 int a[10][10];
 for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
  *(ap+j) = new int[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   *((ap+j)+i) = *(ap+j)+i;
   **((ap+j)+i) = j * 10 + i;

   a[j][i] = j * 10 + i;//(B)
   
   cout<<setw(6)<<**((ap+j)+i);
   //cout<<setw(6)<<a[j][i];
  }
  cout<<endl;
 }
 
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: You can use pastebin.com to paste longer code snippets and put links in comments. In that code there are 3 instances of `*((ap+j)+i)` (which are just `*(ap+j+i)`) and each of them can crash when `i+j>=10`. You need to fix all of them.

Comment: Thanks Kos! I think *((ap+j)+i) = *(ap+j)+i is a bad way to assign the address. When I used *((ap+j)+i) = &a[i], where a[10] is a 1D array of 10 elements and a[i] = j*10+1, everything works fine with pointer operation.

Comment: Can I review the version you obtained? Also you can check it with Valgrind for memory errors just to be sure.